# Java: Collection load factor or how create fixed size set or map

Tags: java, collections, load-factor

In my project i have special utilitarian methods .of() in classes MySet and MyMap to make work easier.

```
    public static <V> Set<V> of(V v1){
        Set<V> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        result.add(v1);
        return result;
    }

    public static <V> Set<V> of(V v1, V... other){
        Set<V> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(result, v1, other);
        return result;
    }
```

I want to use fixed capacity for this methods. My reason is a better performance and memory economy.

for first example:

```
        Set<V> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(1, 1);
```

for second:

```
        Set<V> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(other.length + 1, 1);
```

But as i understand 1f value of "load factor" variable means that limit to doubling buckets count = (capacity * loadfactor). In first example it would be 1 element...

I try to find some info about this question, but found nothing. What is the best way to create fixed sized Set? In my situation i always know how many elements i will need. And i don't want to be overhead, or allocate never used buckets.

Comment: Do you want fixed sized Set/Map or immutable Set/Map? If it's the latter, Java 9 only has such static methods.

Comment: @Eran, they immutable now. I use it like this: "Set<String> strings = MySet.of("1", "2", "3", "4")";

Comment: In that case, use Java 9 Set.of and Map.of. There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: i need fixed sized Set (for example) without capacity expand. Method .of() "knows" how many elements would be in my set, when i will declare it

Comment: @Eran it's java 8 project

Comment: Guava provides these utilities compatible back to Java 6.

Comment: Unless you need these sets for something very specific and specialized, I'd say that this is a case of premature optimization. And if it happens that you actually do have such specialized use case, then you should be using a specialized data-structure, maybe one created by you for this specific case. If I were you, I'd just use the default values and measure with a properly written JMH microbenchmark. Then, if you find any problem, come back here and ask for guidance.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, i use it to define Set with value. It is very old instrument in this project (~java 7), and i want to optimize. Usually, MySet/MyMap using here to define collections with constant values, but sometimes they will be change or supplement by new elements. i don't have task to refactor all using of this classes, but want to make them better. As i think, if they will use enough space, it will be perfect